# Gas water heater not heating water

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

A friend of mine is having problems with his gas water heater.  He sent me the info below so he did try and determine the cause.  It troubles me that he had it "go out" several times a year. I know breezes can "blow out" a pilot light, I'm not sure if that's what happened, but I doubt he'd have to repair it "several times a year".

This might be "opinion based" but should he try and have it repaired, being 9 years old, or just replace it?   9 years seem like a pretty short life for a water heater.

**Here is the info from my friend:**

Here's all the info I have been able to gather.
AO Smith Residential Hot Water Heater
Model:  GCV 50 00L010S83 300
Serial Number:  1139J008321
Manufactured in 2011, so it is 9 years old.  Although the data is very limited, the model I have seems to last for 9-10 years on average.

The Problem

The water heater has gone out 3-4 times a year for about 5 years

•   Now it stopped working at all

o   At first the error message was the light blinking 7 times. This means there is a gas control valve failure.  This is the error message we have typically had previously.

o   A few hours later there was no blinking. Zero blinking means the control is off and the pilot is out

Comment: The gas valve would control the pilot circuit too, right? Seems like that's the place to start. Do you have any reason not to?

Comment: What do you mean by "gone out".  There are many causes for loss of hot water and not all are the fault of the WH itself.  What were the CAUSES of those outages?

Comment: Does the arc wire work properly?

Comment: @jwh20  Those were quotes from my friend. I bolded the intro to his remarks to make it more clear.  I'm not sure what he meant by "gone out" but in my intro paragraph I speculated on that. I just told him I'd check with my buds at SE and see what they had to suggest, I have virtually no experience with gas water heaters.

Comment: Is there a “drip leg” prior to the gas valve? A drip leg is a short stub of pipe pointing down (I put them in after the shutoff valve) . This is there to catch rust flakes and moisture. 1 tiny drop of water can fowl a gas valve. Since you need to turn the gas off to work on the valve check the drip leg if it is full or even close water in the valve could be the problem.